# Save as PDF hidden and protected by password EXCEL sheet

Tags: vba, excel, pdf

I was using this code to save as PDF a hidden worksheet and it was working perfectly:

```
Sub Cite()

Dim wb As Excel.Workbook
Dim Proposalname As String
Dim iVis As XlSheetVisibility
Dim xlName As Excel.Name
Dim FolderPath As String

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
FolderPath = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\"

Proposalname = "Cite for " & CStr(Range("B2").Value)

'Proposal
 Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 With Worksheets(2)
 iVis = .Visible
.Visible = xlSheetVisible
.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
                     Filename:=ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & Proposalname & ".pdf", _
                     Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
                     IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
                     IgnorePrintAreas:=True, _
                     OpenAfterPublish:=True


 .Visible = iVis

 Worksheets(2).Activate


 End With
 Application.ScreenUpdating = True
 End Sub
```

However, now I protected this hidden sheet with a password so people can't unhide it. After doing this, I am not able to generate the PDF like it was working before. I tried to use the command "Unprotect password" and also did not work, it keeps saying that something is wrong with the line ".Visible = xlSheetVisible". Can somebody help me solving this problem please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must unprotect the workbook as well as the worksheet  in order to change the visible property of a worksheet

EDIT:

```
   wb.unprotect "Your password here"
   With Worksheets(2)
         iVis = .Visible
         .Visible = xlSheetVisible
more code here
End With
 wb.protect "Your password here"
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was just using the "unprotect" on the wrong place! You were very helpful :)